# Fragment loads its content but code doesn't update it

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am currently modifying an app from a regular Activity to a TabbedActivity with Fragments, so far I have managed to load the appropiate layout of the fragment to the app once the activity is created, however code that I have on the onCreateView method executes as I am able to debug every line in there, but it has no effect on the layout shown by the fragment, this code is in charge of things like, among others, populate Spinners.

I understand I am doing something wrong somewhere, I just can't quite figure out what it is and where it is happening.

```
public class myClass extends AppCompatActivity {
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabLayout mTabLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_myclass);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    myClass_Fragment ids = new myClass_Fragment ();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content, ids, "fragment one").commit();
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance() {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ids, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "IDS";
            case 1:
                return "Other";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

And the fragment:

```
public class myClass_Fragment extends Fragment {
public myClass_Fragment () {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ids, container, false);
// code that updates views such as spinners
// everything in here works, I can see the content getting retrieved by debugging individual lines
    return  rootView;
}
}
```

All the views are declared in the fragment's layout and once the app loads everything is shown, but with none of the values that get retrieved on the onCreateView method of the fragment.

I think this is pretty much everything that should matter to this issue, I would like to know what am I doing wrong and what could I do to fix it.

As requested, activity_myclass.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".myClass">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:id="@+id/appbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As a side note, everything was working fine on the app before the change to this kind of layout was started, so the problem has to be with this new implementation.

Comment: Where is the newInstance() method inside the PlaceholderFragment?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question.

Comment: Could you post also the activity_myclass.xml layout file?

Comment: Should be there now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can match your requirements, but you can try in this way:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".myClass">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    ...
```

Try to replacing the fragment inside the FrameLayout above, are you able to see the views inside the fragment?

Comment: I added the FrameLayout you suggest and set it on fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, ids, "fragment one").commit(); but I'm still getting the same base layout before all the changes that are made on the onCreateView method.

Comment: In the code you posted above, you are inflating two times the same layout: R.layout.ids , the layout of the fragment you are trying to change.